# Java float to int conversion error

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

Hey Guys I am using a list of lists in java.The list is called deg_grp and the code below shows the output of the deg_grp at a particular index j.

```
for(int k=0;k<deg_grp.get(j).size();k++)
{
     System.out.println(deg_grp.get(j).get(k));
}
```

The output is:

```
1.0
2.0
4.0
6.0
8.0
```

So these are my values. But when I replace the print command by

```
System.out.println((int)deg_grp.get(j).get(k));
```

It is throwing me an error.I need to perform int conversion for indexing purposes later on.The error is:

> incompatible types: Float cannot be converted to int

So I am unable to run the code. Kindly help me out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [Float#intValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intValue()) for your conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unboxed and convert types in one step. You can do `(int)(float) f` however I suggest not using Float, use double or Double for more precision and using `Math.round(d)` to round the result, to minimise errors.

```
System.out.println(Math.round(deg_grp.get(j).get(k)));
```